# Linking a DOM element to another element without copying/cloning

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I have a single HTML file which contains several computation intensive charts which update themselves regularly. The HTML file only shows small parts of the whole content by using JavaScript and a tab-like interface.

My code looks similar to the following:

```
<a href="">Tab1</a> <a href="">Tab2</a> <a href="">Tab3</a>
<div>
    <div id="tab1">
        charts
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        charts
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        charts
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to (for example) show some contents of tab1 in tab3. I can not copy/clone them, as it would use too much resources. I thought about moving the DOM node between tab1 and tab2 everytime the tab changes. But that is not very convenient. Is there another solution? Can I somehow "link" to the content of another DOM element?

Comment: Only solution I see is to give them absolute positioning and just adjust the css when the tab changes.

Comment: Are you sure that cloning the rendered chart is that intensive?

Comment: How about re-thinking how your tabs work?  Maybe your tabs should behave more like buttons, and you can hide/show elements on the page based on which tab is clicked (rather then each tab activating a different div).

Comment: @BradM I thought about that but it would make layouting and showing several different elements quite complex.

Comment: @isherwood Currently, I draw about 30 Charts and Chrome does not really feel snappy anymore. So I doubt that cloning will be a viable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that "snappy" is a practical goal here. That's why loading graphics were invented. :-) Good luck.

Comment: @elevine Thanks, I am thinking about that. The only problem with that approach would be to change the order of the elements based on the tab, but that should be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or what about using appendTo() (http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to move your representation from one tab to another when needed?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Look at this answer here on SO about DOM4 mutation event handlers.  Perhaps it is more in line with what you need.

[Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)

Comment: I'd probably sniff for a change in the original element rather than running setTimeout, especially if it's a fairly complex structure.

Comment: Not a good solution in this case. As I said, the charts are quite computation intensive and your code just copies them regularly. The browser then has to draw two charts instead of one which again needs more resources.